# node js session replaces if request comes at same time

Tags: node.js, session, replace, redis, session-cookies

I have built a node.js application and it is working as expected. The only problem that i am facing now is when the code receives same request from two different session then the result(outcome) is changing. That is First request is getting the the result of second request and second request result is same.

my code :

```
app.get('/userpage',function(req,res){
if(req.session.user){
  var a = req.session.user; //stored in redis server.
   var b = req.session.userid //stored in redis server
   //call function(req,res,a,b);
 }
}

//Function
exports.functionname = function(req,res,a,b){
//do something
 result = a+b;
  return result;
}
```

the result of first request is replacing with the second session result. And if i refresh page again individually i get the correct result for both the sessions. This  only happens if i put the same request and same time. Please help!

Note: I am storing the session details in Redis server. nopt inserting anytthing to my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it by myself, it was happening because of missing callbacks. Node js needs to have callback in order to wait for the output